# Полнотекстовый поиск в MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, search, полнотекстовый-поиск

Здравствуйте!

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с полнотекстовым индексом в MongoDB.

```
> db.ftsc.insert({"name":"10pisem+1"});
> db.ftsc.insert({"name":"20pisem+1"});
> db.ftsc.insert({"name":"20pisem 2 письма"});
> db.ftsc.insert({"name":"20pisem 2 письмо"}); 
>
> db.ftsc.ensureIndex({"name":"text"});
>
> db.ftsc.find( { $text: { $search: "письм" } } ); // результат 0, хотя я ожидал 2 записи
>
> db.ftsc.find( { $text: { $search: "письмо" } } );
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ba8e56fd2bc6bd8af53531"), "name" : "20pisem 2 письмо" }
>
> db.ftsc.find( { $text: { $search: "pis" } } ); // результат 0
>
> db.ftsc.find( { $text: { $search: "1" } } );
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ba8e35fd2bc6bd8af5352f"), "name" : "20pisem+1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ba8e23fd2bc6bd8af5352e"), "name" : "10pisem+1" }
>
> db.ftsc.find( { $text: { $search: "10" } } ); //результат 0
>
> db.ftsc.find( { $text: { $search: "m+1" } } );
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ba8e35fd2bc6bd8af5352f"), "name" : "20pisem+1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ba8e23fd2bc6bd8af5352e"), "name" : "10pisem+1" }
>
> db.ftsc.find( { $text: { $search: "m+" } } ); // результат 0
```

Как правильно настроить индекс, что бы он искал по вхождениям подстроки?

P.S.: использовать регулярные выражения не предлагать.

Answer (score 5):

Зависит от вашей версии mongo
Если она младше 2.6 (или 2.4, не помню) то надо включать поиск руками.

```
mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true
```

Так же, по стандарту там не русский язык. Если не так делали -

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { name: "text" }, { default_language: "russian" })
```

А вообщем, Вам сюда - [Полнотекстовый поиск в MongoDB](http://habrahabr.ru/post/174457/)

Comment: @Владимир Васюков - Да, всё это читал, параметры включены. По поводу русского это один вопрос, а вот почему не ищет вот с этим параметром: 

> db.ftsc.find( { $text: { $search: "pis" } } ); // результат 0

непонятно. При установке русского языка по запросу "письм" тоже ничего не ищет.